# How to use NotificationListenerService to block notification in android

Tags: java, android, notifications

**NOTE:** I'm aware that this question somehow can be a duplicate. Still I'm asking this as I found no tutorial or any proper answer for the above question.

I'm making an app which has a feature that user can block the notifications. The user can select either to block all the notifications or block only selected apps. To select apps for blocking notifications I have created a `RecyclerView` where user can choose which app to be blocked, and to block all notifications there is a master switch. The android `Rooms` are used to save data   even after the activity is destroyed.

Following is a screenshot of the app.

[image: A screenshot of the app]

All I need to know is how can I implement the `NotificationListenerService` in order to block notifications. As I mentioned before I want only to block notifications when the app is selected in the `RecyclerView` or the `Block all notifications`, master switch is turned on. Anyone who can give me a proper guide is appreciated.

PS: There are 8 files in the project and I have no idea how to post them here, any solutions for that also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way! Obviously I created a `NotificationListener` class which extends the [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) class and then override the [`onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification,%20android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.RankingMap)) function.

To block all the notifications I created a variable in `MainActivity.java` named `public static boolean BLOCK_ALL = false;`. This variable would change as the `Block All Notification` switch in the screenshot changed.

```
    SwitchMaterial blockAllNotifications = findViewById(R.id.blockAllNotifications);
    blockAllNotifications.setChecked(BLOCK_ALL);
    blockAllNotifications.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                BLOCK_ALL = isChecked;
    });
```

And in the [`onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification,%20android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.RankingMap)) function in the `NotificationListener` I added following condition;

```
    if(MainAcitivity.BLOCK_ALL)cancelAllNotifications();
```

Whenever the `Block All Notifiction` switch is turned on it's going to call [`cancelAllNotification()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#cancelAllNotifications()) function and block all the notifications.

At last in order to block notifications of each package I did something as follow. As I mentioned in the question, I have all the apps whose switch is turned on in a `Room` named `BlockedList`. Therefore I added a logic; if the package which has posted the notification is in the `BlockedList` I blocked that app's notifications with [`cancelNotification(String key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#cancelNotification(java.lang.String)).

```
appNameList = appsDB.dbDAO().getAllAppNames();
if(appNameList.contains(getApplicationName(sbn.getPackageName()))){  // if the blocked list has the app name of the notification
    cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
}

/***
* getApplicationName: get the application name of the notification belongs to
* @param pack: the package name; a StatusBarNotification.getPackageName()
* @return
*/
private String getApplicationName(String pack){
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo appInfo;
    try{
        appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(pack, 0);  // getting the application info
    }catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        appInfo = null;
    }
    final String appName = (String) (appInfo != null? pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo) : "(unknown)");  // if the appInfo is not null get the label of the Application
    return appName;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Every notification(StatusBarNotification) has its own packagename,

```
public String getPackageName() {
    return pkg;
}
```

I think you can block it through StatusBarNotification attribute